# Vuetify grid across components: can columns in children behave as columns in parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

For a specific layout for my application, I need to display certain columns inside certains v-rows only if conditions are met.

The conditions being the same each time, and to avoid re-writing v-col after v-col, I decided to write a component which contains the three columns I which to display inside the row. The idea would be to use it like this:

```
                 <v-row justify="start">
                    <v-col cols="12" md="2">
                      <!-- My first column, that's always here... -->
                    </v-col>
                    <MyComponent v-if="myCondition" :data="myData"/>
                  </v-row>
```

In turn, MyComponent looks like this:

```
<template>
 <span>
  <v-col cols="12" md="4">
    <!-- stuff -->
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" md="2">
    <!-- stuff -->
  </v-col>      
  <v-col cols="12" md="4">
    <!-- stuff -->
  </v-col>
</span>
```

When rendering this code however, Vuetify considers the whole MyComponent as being part of a single col, and as such displays it all squished. What I expected is it to render all the columns properly, and to have a full row.

Is there anyway to work around this problem?

Comment: The problem here is the span tag. The columns need to be a direct child of the row. I would move the three columns out of the component and back into your main component then wrap those 3 columns in a template tag with the v-if

Comment: @LLai that did the trick, thank you! I ended up keeping it in a separate component, but simply adding a v-row instead of the span. Feel free to submit this as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: np! glad I could help. good call on adding a v-row. that is a good way to keep it componetized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the span tag. The columns need to be a direct child of the row. I would move the three columns out of the component and back into your main component then wrap those 3 columns in a template tag with the v-if

```html
<v-row justify="start">
  <v-col cols="12" md="2">
    <!-- My first column, that's always here... -->
  </v-col>
  <template v-if="myCondition">
    <v-col cols="12" md="4"></v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" md="4"></v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" md="4"></v-col>
  </template>
</v-row>
```

or alternatively as you mentioned. you could use a v-row as the root element in your child component

Parent component

```html
<v-row justify="start">
  <v-col cols="12" md="2">
    <!-- My first column, that's always here... -->
  </v-col>
  <v-col v-if="myCondition" cols="12" md="10">
    <MyComponent :data="myData"/>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Child component

```html
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" md="4"></v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" md="4"></v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" md="4"></v-col>
</v-row>
```